# Evitar que Refresh na página gere consultas adicionais ao BD MVC C#

Tags: c#, mvc

O caso é o seguinte.
A minha ActionResult faz uma consulta pesada no banco e retorna dados aleatorios por definição de negocio.

O usuario pode dar um refresh na tela. Se atualizar a pagina, perde o que foi feito e o retorno da query é outro.

Alguem sabe como evitar que ao executar o link novamente ou refresh impeça que minha ActionResult seja executada novamente?

Comment: Complementando. Se eu controlar via sessao que a consulta ja foi feita, o Objeto de retorno dessa ActionResult ficará como null. pois ela é iniciada nessa ActionResult obviamente.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. Seria bom se você colocasse parte do código par entender-se melhor.

Comment: e se guardar o resultado da consulta na session, e checar, se tem resultado na session retorna ele, se nao executa a consulta ?!

Answer (score 0):

Quando você fizer a busca pela primeira vez, guarde em uma session ou ViewBag, algo que diga que já foi feito a busca, dai quando o usario atualizar a pagina, você verifica via javascript no evento reload. Exemplo com ViewBag:

**ActionResult**

```
ViewBag.Executou = 1;
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if(@ViewBag.Executou == 1){     
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Assim a pagina será executada apenas uma vez.

*Obs: este evento não funciona no Opera.*